# Product Carousel Extension Recommendation

Tags: extensions

I'm looking for a recommendation for a product carousel extension (not banner carousel - specifically for products!). I'm looking for something similar to the carousel which handles the `'Customers who bought this also bought'` feature on [www.dx.com](http://www.dx.com).

Here's an example (near bottom of the page):

[560N2 300Mbps 802.11b/g/n Wi-Fi AP / Repeater Adapter w/ 3dBi Antenna - White + Black (EU Plug)](http://www.dx.com/p/560n2-300mbps-802-11b-g-n-wi-fi-ap-repeater-adapter-w-3dbi-antenna-white-black-eu-plug-207352#.VB_WvhawJ7s)

[image: Product Carousel]

It would be ideal if the carousel could be created in the backend and implemented via block/cms page by a non-developer.

Comment: Why do you need an extension? You already have the "customers who bought..." products. Just take any carousel you like and integrate it in the template.

Comment: I'm not looking for the `also bought` feature, I'm just looking for that carousel functionality which can easily be implemented in Magento by somebody without development knowledge (i.e using a block or something of sorts), I was hoping there's an extension which has this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-category-product-carousel.html
```

I think this might be helpful to you.